# Linear Regression - Not correct output

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I have a database of two columns["A", "B"] where "A" is the input variable and "B" is the target variable. All values are in integers.

My code:

```
X.shape
>>(2540, 1)

y.shape
>>(2540, 1)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X)
X = scaler.transform(X)

import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
np.random.rand(4)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test  = train_test_split(X,y,test_size = 0.2)
```

Linear Regression from Sklearn

```
regr = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
regr.fit(X_train, y_train)  

print ('Coefficients: ', regr.coef_)
print ('Intercept: ',regr.intercept_)          
>>Coefficients:  [[43.95569425]]
>>Intercept:  [100.68681298]
```

I got R2 value of 0.93

The last record in X_train is 3687 and the corresponding y_train value is 212.220001

I used the last record for prediction, like

```
regr.predict([[3687]] )
>>array([161825.22279211])
```

I do not understand What is happening, I excepted the predicted value will be around 212.

But, The predicted value is 161825

Could you please explain what is the reason, thanks

Comment: 1) Fitting a linear regression to an arbitrary data set does not guarantee that prediction for all data points in the training set will be reasonable. 2) To evaluate performance, you should not look at individual predictions. 3) You shoul evaluate on the held-out data `X_test` and `y_test` instead of a data point from `X_train`. 4) Is `3687` a scaled value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps you need to pass your test data through the scaler before feeding to the regression. 
try `reg.predict(scaler.transform([3687])`

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot to scale the value, Thanks, I spent half an hour for finding the answer

Comment: The OP has mentioned it as X_train